# How to add TensorRT Plugin to a non-TRT model?

Tags: python, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0, onnx, tensorrt

I want to add BatchedNMSDynamic_TRT plugin to my SSD ONNX model in the end. I want output model to be also in ONNX form only. (or any other format but not TRT model.) My current model has two output, one related to coordinate of bbox and another is corresponding confidence scores.
Please help me on this. Python code is preferred.